# Javascript and Jquery Quotes generator

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I am trying to generate a random quotes using Javascript and Jquery.
Can someone tell me why it isn't working? I wrote a random generate function inside the document.ready and using it to generate random array index, but it is not out putting any quotes. Please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Random Quotes</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

  <div id="box">
      <p id="quotesBox"></p>
      <button  type="button" id="quoteButton" class="buttons" class="btn btn-primary">Give me a Quote</button>
      <button  type="button" id="clearButton" class="buttons" class="btn btn-primary">Clear</button>
  </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


$(document).ready(function(){
  var randomQuotes = [
                    "Doh",
                    "Mom, where's my meatloaf",
                    "This is spartan",
                    "Stay here,I will be back ",
                    "You talking to me? You talking to me??"
                    ];


  $("#quoteButton").on('click', function(){
    function randomQuotes() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * randomQuotes.length);
    }

    $("#quotesBox").text(randomQuotes[randomQuotes()]);
  });


  $("#clearButton").on('click', function(){
    $("#quotesBox").text("");
  });

});


#box {
  height: 500px;
  width:  500px;
  background: rgb(205, 255, 255);
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.buttons {
  position: 0px 0px 0px 70px;
  margin: 100px -130px 0px 150px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color:  #FF00FF;
  background: white;
}

#quotesBox {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Can't have a variable and a function with same name in same scope. Change name of one of them. What error is thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the following changes to your javascript:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqpBzj

```
var randomQuotes = [
    "doh",
    "Mom, where's my meatloaf",
    "This is spartan",
    "Stay here,I will be back ",
    "You talking to me? You talking to me??"
];

$("#quoteButton").on('click', function() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomQuotes.length);
  $("#quotesBox").text(randomQuotes[x]);
});

$("#clearButton").on('click', function() {
  $("#quotesBox").text("");
});
```

-Reasons For Changes-

1) You don't need the $(document).ready(function(){}); if you are simply adding event handlers

2) Refrain from defining functions within other functions when it is not necessary. You can simplify that by just passing the Math.floor(...) to a variable.

3) Don't be afraid to write things out. No reason to mega-condense things all into one line.

4) Keep function/variable names unique or more descriptive. It is confusing for other users when they see an array and a function with very similar names.

Answer (score 0):

The function and array's name seems the same, it works when one of them is changed

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var randomQuotes = [
                    "Doh",
                    "Mom, where's my meatloaf",
                    "This is spartan",
                    "Stay here,I will be back ",
                    "You talking to me? You talking to me??"
                    ];


  $("#quoteButton").on('click', function(){
    function getRandomQuotes() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * randomQuotes.length);
    }

    $("#quotesBox").text(randomQuotes[getRandomQuotes()]);
  });
});
```